# Question about divide result from the same column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I am trying to write statement in SQL Server. What I am trying to do is to get the result of count records in columns end with "R" divide the count of all the records. So it is basically the statement of a column with a statement " count (invoice) where Invoice like "%R" / count( Invoice)"

Here is my code without the divide calculation. I only come up with statement without the divide calculation.

```
SELECT 
    Invoice,
    COUNT(ART_CURRENT__TRANSACTION.Invoice) AS Number_Revisions,
    MAX(ART_CURRENT__TRANSACTION.[Customer]) AS "Customer",
    MAX(ARM_MASTER__CUSTOMER.Name) AS "Name",
    MAX(ART_CURRENT__TRANSACTION.[Job]) AS Job
FROM 
    ART_CURRENT__TRANSACTION
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    ARM_MASTER__CUSTOMER ON ARM_MASTER__CUSTOMER.Customer = ART_CURRENT__TRANSACTION.Customer
WHERE
    Invoice LIKE '%R'
GROUP BY
    Invoice;
```

What I am trying to ask is how can I add a column that calculate the number of invoice end with "R"/ NUMBER OF INVOICE.

Thank you guys!

Comment: Sample data and desired results, provided as tabular text, would help others to properly understand your question.

Comment: Your query shows one result row per %R invoice. Is this what you want? And for each such invoice you show the number of transactions. But now you also want to show the invoice's number of transactions divided by the total number of transactions in the table? Yes?

Comment: On a side note: It looks like you expect there to be only one customer per invoice. Is this so? Otherwise "Customer" and "Name" could be two different customers. I even think that you expect there to be just one job per invoice. In that case you may want to consider a separate invoice table with the customer and job, so as to not store the data redundantly (and potentially inconsistently).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I am trying to do is to get the result of count records in Columns end with "R" divide the count of all the records.

You seem to want this calculation:

```
SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN t.Invoice LIKE '%R' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END)
FROM ART_CURRENT__TRANSACTION t;
```

This assumes that `invoice` is in the transaction table.  I don't think a join is necessary for what you want to do.